# Google Chrome Browser Glitch

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, cross-browser

I am having trouble with displaying my gallery in various browsers.

Everything looks a treat in Firefox, however when viewed in Chrome or Safari, the Our Work section (light box gallery) is heavily wonky.

The site is http://entirecreative.com/stone/#ourwork

the css of the effected elements are:

```
.s3blockcontainer{
max-width:960px;
margin:0 auto;
height:auto;
text-align:center;
}

.s3block{
height:320px;
width:320px;
display:inline-block;
margin:0;
float:left;


}


.imagewrapper{

height:320px;

display:inline-block;
width:320px;
overflow:hidden;
}

  .s3block img{
height:320px;
width:320px;

}


  .s3block:hover img{

margin:-5px -5px;
height:330px;
width:330px;

}

.s3blockblurb{
position:absolute;
height:320px;
width:320px;
/*padding:75px 35px 50px 35px;*/
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;

}

.s3blockfaded{
/*position:absolute;*/
padding-top:46%;
height:320px;
width:320px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:rgba(247,248,248,0);
color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.s3blockfaded:hover{
height:320px;
width:320px;
display:inline-block;
background-color:rgba(247,248,248,0.5);
color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
}
```

thanks for any help/suggestions!